# System.Net.WebException - Internal Server error 500

Tags: c#, console

While I am doing a web API using C# console Application using HttpWebRequest an exception occurs

> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Here is my code:

```
string postURL = "";
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postURL);

webRequest.Method = "POST";

webRequest.Headers.Add("token", "ee22c61a55bd0629c8c8a63a8c8b73ed");            

webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

webRequest.Headers.Add("ContentType","application/json");
int bufferSize = 1024;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
int byteCount = 0;
FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(@"D:\audio\smallwave.zip");
webRequest.ContentLength = finfo.Length;
// webRequest.SendChunked = true;

using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"D:\audio\smallwave.zip"))
using (Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    while ((byteCount = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0)
    {
        requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteCount);
    }
}

HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
// using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    String result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

An error is showing like

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in
>   System.dll
>   Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (500)
>   Internal Server Error.

Comment: Does the httpwebresponse contains this error or does this happen while debugging the code?

Comment: Ask the remote server what internal error it encountered.

Comment: One problem I see is that you are setting the content type to json (twice) but you are not sending json.

Comment: i want to upload a zip file,even if i changed the  json to zip, the same error is showing as "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using HTTPClient


string baseUrl = "https://vspark-demo.vocitec.com/transcribe/M2ComSys-Pilot/eng1CCStereo/";



            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            HttpContent content = new StringContent("file");
            HttpContent DictionaryItems = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
       new KeyValuePair<string, string>("token", "ee22c61a55bd0629c8c8a63a8c8b73ed"),
   });
            form.Add(content, "files");
            // form.Add(DictionaryItems, "data");
            form.Add(new StringContent("ee22c61a55bd0629c8c8a63a8c8b73ed"), "token");
             var stream = new FileStream(@"D:\audio\variety.wav", FileMode.Open);
            content = new StreamContent(stream);
            content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
            {
                Name = "file",
                FileName = "variety.wav"
            };
            form.Add(content);

            HttpResponseMessage response = null;

            try
            {
                response = (client.PostAsync(baseUrl, form)).Result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(response);
            var k = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine(k);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Is this the solution to your question or is it an edit to the question? If it is an edit please be aware you can edit your original question you should not add additional information as an answer.